# Eclipse breakpoint builds workspace

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, building

I have a problem with my eclipse. It is building the workspace everytime I add, remove (one or all) breakpoint(s)... The building can take quite some time and since I add and remove the breakpoints a lot when I'm debugging, this is irritating. Is there somebody who has the same problem ? Is there a fix or is there a way to know exactly what triggers the builds ?

Thanks !

Comment: How are you adding breakpoints?

Comment: Right click on project, select properties. Look under Builders. What builders are configured for the eclipse project? Also, what version of Eclipse and what programming language?

Comment: I double click on the left f the pages. I code in java, the version is Kepler.

Comment: The builders are: Java Builder, Validation, Maven Project Builder

Comment: Have you been able to fix the problem? If not: have you enabled 'Project > Build automatically'? And if so, does it disappear if you disable the option?